# How do I update a JLabel during run time

Tags: java, swing

the JLabel's name is set to an int which changes as the user modifies the number, i tried label.revalidate and Label.repaint after the user changes the int value. i have seen in similar questions people suggest creating a new jlabel everytime, but im wondering if there is a simpler way? the code is very long so i will summerize when needed.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class officia {
    static JFrame Frame;
    static JPanel Panel;
    static JTextField healthPlace;
    static String health="0";
    static JButton begin;
    static JLabel heart;
    static int loop;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Panel = new JPanel();
    
    Frame = new JFrame();
    Frame.setSize(500,1000);
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.add(Panel);
    Panel.setLayout(null);
    //adds panel and frame
    
    healthPlace = new JTextField();
    healthPlace.setBounds(170, 130, 165, 25);
    Panel.add(healthPlace);
    
    begin = new JButton("Begin");
    begin.setBounds(217, 185, 70, 25);
    Panel.add(begin);
    
    while(loop==1)
    loop=0;
        
    heart = new JLabel(health);
    heart.setBounds(150, -85, 500, 500);
    Panel.add(heart);
    
    Frame.setVisible(true); 
    //inputs gui's
    
    
    ActionListener beginPressed = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
            health = healthPlace.getText();
            loop=1;
    }
};
begin.addActionListener(beginPressed);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're working in a event driven environment, that is, something happens and you respond to it.

This means, you're `while-loop` is ill-conceived and is probably the source of your issue.  How can the `ActionListener` for the button be added when the loop is running, but you seem to using the `ActionListener` to exit the loop...

I modified you code slightly, so when you press the button, it will update the label.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class officia {

    static JFrame Frame;
    static JPanel Panel;
    static JTextField healthPlace;
    static String health = "0";
    static JButton begin;
    static JLabel heart;
    static int loop;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Panel = new JPanel();

        Frame = new JFrame();
        Frame.setSize(500, 1000);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.add(Panel);
        Panel.setLayout(null);
        //adds panel and frame  

        healthPlace = new JTextField();
        healthPlace.setBounds(170, 130, 165, 25);
        Panel.add(healthPlace);

        begin = new JButton("Begin");
        begin.setBounds(217, 185, 70, 25);
        Panel.add(begin);

        // This is ... interesting, but a bad idea
//        while (loop == 1) {
//            loop = 0;
//        }


        heart = new JLabel(health);
        heart.setBounds(150, -85, 500, 500);
        Panel.add(heart);

        Frame.setVisible(true);
        //inputs gui's

        ActionListener beginPressed = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                health = healthPlace.getText();
                loop ++;
                heart.setText(Integer.toString(loop));
            }
        };
        begin.addActionListener(beginPressed);
    }
}
```

`JLabel#setText` is what's known as a stateful property, that is, it will trigger an update that will cause it to be painted, so, if it's not updating, you're doing something wrong.

## Possible runnable example (of what I think you want to do)

You're working a very rich UI framework.  One if it's, many, features, is the layout management framework, something you should seriously take the time to learn to understand and use.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

Below is a relatively simple example which shows one way you might "swicth" between views based on a response to a user input

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new BasePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public BasePane() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            StartPane startPane = new StartPane(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cardLayout.show(BasePane.this, "HeartPane");
                }
            });

            HeartPane heartPane = new HeartPane();

            add(startPane, "StartPane");
            add(heartPane, "HeartPane");
        }        
    }

    public class StartPane extends JPanel {

        public StartPane(ActionListener actionListener) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton start = new JButton("Begin");
            add(start);

            start.addActionListener(actionListener);
        }

    }

    public class HeartPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField heartTextField;
        private JLabel heartLabel;

        public HeartPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            heartLabel = new JLabel("Heart");
            heartTextField = new JTextField(10);

            add(heartLabel);
            add(heartTextField);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it only occurred to me that I didn't need a loop at all after seeing it.

Comment: TLDR; `JLabel.setText(String)` works

Comment: @Roe If only it was that simple 